# . NgFor only supports binding to iterables such as Arrays. any body help will be appreciated

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am facing the error when i am passing the data to array, everything is fine api call is
returning the json object anybody help will be appreciated

my **component.ts**

```typescript
     account: account_details[];

     ngOnInit(): void {
       this.Backend.userdetails(this.x).subscribe(data => {
       console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
       this.account=data
    });
```

my **account_details.ts**

```typescript
     export interface account_details
    {
      Account_number:number;
      Account_type: string;
      Activationcode: string;
      Balance: number;
      DOB: Date;
      Date_of_creation: Date;
      Email_address: string;
      ID: number;
      Loan: string;
      Loan_amount: number;
      Loan_status: string;
      Name: string;
      Password: string;
      Verified: string;
     }
```

my **service.ts**

```typescript
     userdetails(activation_code):Observable<account_details[]>
     {
      return this.http.get<account_details[]>. 
      ('http://127.0.0.1:8080/api/Home/account_details? 
      activationcode='+activation_code)

     }
```

Comment: From the backend, are you receiving an array?

Comment: @OwenKelvin my problem is resolved with the below answer i got a new i have changed the title it would be helpful if you help

Comment: It will better to rollback changes to this question and ask a new one since this one was already answered

Comment: @OwenKelvin my limitation is reached so any help to resolve

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
userdetails(activation_code):Observable<account_details>
     {
      return this.http.get<account_details>. 
      ('http://127.0.0.1:8080/api/Home/account_details? 
      activationcode='+activation_code)

     }
```

Is your problem perhaps you are returning:

`Observable<account_details>`

instead of

`Observable<account_details[]>`

?

```
userdetails(activation_code):Observable<account_details[]>
     {
      return this.http.get<account_details[]>. 
      ('http://127.0.0.1:8080/api/Home/account_details? 
      activationcode='+activation_code)

     }
```